# command line: heroku pg:psql ... gets 'psql: error: SSL error: certificate verify failed'

Tags: ssl, heroku, command-line-interface, psql

heroku pg:psql suddenly not happy.

```
π main ✗ ❯ heroku pg:psql postgresql-xyz --app xyz
    --> Connecting to postgresql-xyz
    psql: error: SSL error: certificate verify failed
    FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "47.123.123.123", user "abc", database "xyz", SSL off
     ▸    psql exited with code 2

π main ❯ heroku -v
heroku/7.59.1 darwin-x64 node-v12.21.0
```

I notice "SSL off".  How to turn in on via HEROKU cli?  Or is it a setting in "Config Vars" at heroku.com ?

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS, this did the trick.
Postgres seems to install 'root.crt' in ~.postgresql folder. Somehow, referring to it as 'root.key' in the connection string works.

```
psql "sslmode=require sslrootcert=/Users/abc123/.postgresql/root.key user=abc password=xyz host=ec1.compute-1.amazonaws.com dbname=d123"
```

Comment: Thank you. I had been pulling my hair trying to make psql connect to a Linode managed PostgreSQL database using SSL, and simply renaming the cert file to `root.key` made it work.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, but may cause other database connections to have issues:

```
cd ~/.postgresql
rm root.crt
```